# Numbered fields in google docs

Tags: google-docs

In google docs I would like to have headings that is named

§ 1 Heading

§ 2 Other heading

As I have understood, there is no way to enumerate headings, but is there any field (like page numbers) that you could use instead?

My last resort will be having a script that updates the headings if I move them around, but a more native approach would be nice.